# Rolling count of changes between row elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| Identification | Date (day/month/year) | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | 100 | abc |
| 123 | 02/01/2022 | 200 | acb |
| 123 | 03/01/2022 | 300 | ary |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 200 | abc |
| 124 | 02/01/2022 | 900 | abc |
| 124 | 03/01/2022 | 900 | abc |

I am trying to create two separate 'change' columns, one for x and y separately, that is keeping a rolling count of how many times a given element is changing over time. I would like my output to look something like this:

| Identification | Date (day/month/year) | X | Y | Change X | Change Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 | 100 | abc | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 02/01/2022 | 200 | acb | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 03/01/2022 | 300 | ary | 2 | 2 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 | 200 | abc | 0 | 0 |
| 124 | 02/01/2022 | 900 | abc | 1 | 0 |
| 124 | 03/01/2022 | 900 | abc | 0 | 0 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using pandas for this, please add pandas tag in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most performant but gets the job done:

```
def consec_count(arr):
    total = 0
    out = np.zeros(len(arr), dtype=np.int32)
    acc = arr[0]
    for idx, el in enumerate(arr):
        if el == acc or el == np.nan or el == pd.NA:
            total = 0
        else:
            total += 1
            acc = el
        out[idx] = total
    return out

df[['Change X', 'Change Y']] = df.groupby('Identification', 
                                   group_keys=False)[['X', 'Y']].transform(
                                                        lambda x : consec_count(x.values))
```

And the output:

```
   Identification Date (day/month/year)    X    Y  Change X  Change Y
0             123            01/01/2022  100  abc         0         0
1             123            02/01/2022  200  acb         1         1
2             123            03/01/2022  300  ary         2         2
3             124            01/01/2022  200  abc         0         0
4             124            02/01/2022  900  abc         1         0
5             124            03/01/2022  900  abc         0         0
```

Comment: This works great! One issue I forgot to mention though is that some of my ids have consecutive nulls (E.g.: Id #123 might have element x = 0 in both 01/01/2022 and 02/01/2022). When I run your script it includes this scenario into the overall count which I don't want

Comment: You can just add that the value can't be zero if the condition in the loop! I'll add it later if you can't manage yourself.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated - Also, just to clarify, I mean nulls not zeros

Comment: @Mitchell I'm not entirely sure what you mean but after the modification now, it shouldn't take nulls into account. If it `None` is also an option, then just add or with the `or` clause where the total is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import pandas as pd

for col in df.columns[2:]:
    df[f'Change {col}'] = None
    for id, group in df.groupby('Identification'):
        df.loc[df['Identification'] == id, f'Change {col}'] = \
            list(accumulate(group.index[:-1], lambda x, y: x + 1 if group.loc[y, col] != group.loc[y + 1, col] else 0, initial=0))

df

   Identification Date(day/month/year)    X    Y Change X Change Y
0             123           01/01/2022  100  abc        0        0
1             123           02/01/2022  200  acb        1        1
2             123           03/01/2022  300  ary        2        2
3             124           01/01/2022  200  abc        0        0
4             124           02/01/2022  900  abc        1        0
5             124           03/01/2022  900  abc        0        0
```